# laravel "invalid host" on loadbalancer redirects

Tags: laravel, reverse-proxy

Background: I'm working on an api which I host on ec2 servers.  I just finish the login and set up an nginx loadbalancer which redirect to the said server's internal ip's. The domain name points to the load balancer.

This used to work well with code igniter, but now I keep getting an "invalid host" problem.

I tried googling it and it found some things about `trusted proxies` so I installed what fideloper made and tried his post as well (I've followed a guide by fideloper on `laravel-4-trusted-proxies` and used and tried his trusted sample on github: [`fideloper/TrustedProxy`](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy)) but I still get the same error:

```
UnexpectedValueException
Invalid Host "api.myserver.im, api.myserver.im"

    // as the host can come from the user (HTTP_HOST and depending on the configuration, SERVER_NAME too can come from the user)
    // check that it does not contain forbidden characters (see RFC 952 and RFC 2181)
    if ($host && !preg_match('/^\[?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-:\]_]+\.?)+$/', $host)) {
        throw new \UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('Invalid Host "%s"', $host));
    }
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as well. I had to resort to modifying the UrlGenerator.php file, which is part of the framework (bad I know...) just to get this to work.

So here's my "temporary" solution.

Create an array value to your app.php config file. e.g:

```
return array(
    'rooturl'   => 'https://www.youractualdomainname.com',
    ...
```

Next add the below modification in your UrlGenerator.php file <-- (trunk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php)

```
<?php namespace Illuminate\Routing;
use Config;
...
protected function getRootUrl($scheme, $root = null)
{
    $approoturl = Config::get('app.rooturl');

    $root = isset($approoturl) ? $approoturl : $this->request->root();

    return $root;

    // if (is_null($root))
    // {
    //  $root = $this->forcedRoot ?: $this->request->root();
    // }

    // $start = starts_with($root, 'http://') ? 'http://' : 'https://';

    // return preg_replace('~'.$start.'~', $scheme, $root, 1);
}
```

Do note that composer update will revert your modification.